# I want to save all outputs in a variable-type list

Tags: python, for-loop, range

```
for i in range(9999999):
if i <= 9:
    print '000',i,'000000'
elif i <= 99:
    print '000',i,'00000'
elif i <= 999:
    print '000',i,'0000'
elif i <= 9999:
    print '000',i,'000'
elif i <= 99999:
    print '000',i,'00'
elif i <= 999999:
    print '000',i,'0'
elif i <= 9999999:
    print '000',i
```

I want to save all outputs in a variable-type list
The output looks like this : 000 000 0000

Comment: What's `variable-type` ?

Comment: variables don't have types in python.

Comment: var = ['I mean that','list']

Comment: make empty list which `new_data = []` and then use `append` to save your output

Comment: Note that you will never process the value 9999999, unless you change the `range()` argument, i.e. unless your first line becomes `for in in range(10000000):`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below shows a simpler way to generate your strings, and also shows how to append them to a list instead of printing them.

```
lst = []
for i in range(9999999):
    if 100 <= i <= 999:
        prefix = "050"
    else:
        prefix = "000"
    i_str = str(i)
    suffix = "0" * (7-len(i_str))
    result = prefix + " " + i_str + " " + suffix
    # or result = " ".join((prefix, i_str, suffix))
    lst.append(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, for each `i` less than 9 999 999, your goal is to build a string formed by three parts:

- '000';
- the string representation of `i`;
- a sequence of zeros depending on the length of the string representation of `i`.

You can achieve this goal with a simple list comprehension:

```
lst = ['000 %d %s'.strip() % (i, '0' * (7-len(str(i)))) for i in xrange(9999999)]
```

Note however that such a big list takes some time to be built and occupies some memory.

In case you don't need the whole list at once, but you are going to process its elements one by one, I suggest you to create a generator:

```
lst_gen = ('000 %d %s'.strip() % (i, '0' * (7-len(str(i)))) for i in xrange(9999999))
```

and then loop over it:

```
for s in lst_gen:
    print s
```

or ask for subsequent elements and process them one by one:

```
s = next(lst_gen)
print s
s = next(lst_gen)
print s
```